# PHP cases and GET

Tags: php, sql, web

I am trying to use the cases function to use for navigation on my site.

However when I try to use it with a php request a GET, it gives me this error:

```
Warning: include(work.php?user=EEN0422) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in E:\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\vtlog\browse.php on line 16

Warning: include(work.php?user=EEN0422) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in E:\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\vtlog\browse.php on line 16

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'work.php?user=EEN0422' for inclusion (include_path='.;./includes;./pear') in E:\vhosts\example.com\httpdocs\vtlog\browse.php on line 16
```

The script of browse.php is:

```
<?php
$status = $_GET['status'];
$user = $_GET['user'];

switch ($status) {
    case "working":
        include("index2.php");
        break;
    case "log":
        include("admin.php");
        break;
    case "admin":
        include("settings.php");
        break;  
    case "users":
        include("work.php?user=$user");
        break;
}
?>
```

And for the work.php which is the problem here:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['LoggedIn']) header("location: settingsauth.php");


$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="root";
$db_name="db";
$tbl_name="log";

$user=$_GET['user'];


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT *, (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start)) / 60.0 / 60.0 as hours_difference FROM $tbl_name WHERE user='$user'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if ($result === false) { echo "An error occurred."; }

?>
<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Start</strong></td>
<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>End</strong></td>
<td width="30%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Kommentar</strong></td>
<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Tid</strong></td>
<td width="5%" align="center" bgcolor="E6E6E6"></td>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<title>VTLog - <? echo $rows['user']; ?></title>
<tr>    
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['start']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['end']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['comment']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?$var = number_format($rows['hours_difference'],2);
$var = number_format($var,1);
echo $var; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="editwork.php?editid=<? echo $rows['editid']; ?>"><img src="ret.jpg" alt="Ret"></a><form action="workstatus.php" method="get"><input type="hidden" name="editit" value="<? echo $rows['editid']; ?>" /><input type="submit" value="Slet" /></form></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
mysql_close();
?>
<tr>
<td align="left" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><a href="settings.php">Tilbage til oversigt</a></td><td colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6">Total arbejdstid: <?php $var = number_format($rows['hours_difference'],2);
$var = number_format($var,1);
echo $var;?></td><td bgcolor="#E6E6E6" colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can't pass query strings using `include()`, arguments to said construct take the passed file name verbatim, e.g. `work.php?user=EEN0422` as a file.

Answer (score 2):

You don't include PHP files like web URL paths.

```
// Wrong
include("work.php?user=$user");
```

Instead do this:

```
include("work.php");
// Which now has access to the current variables including $user
```

Whenever you `include()/require()` a new PHP file - it is just as if the code was inserted right where the include statement is. This new file has the same access to variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass query string in `include()` or `require()`

Wrong: `include("work.php?user=$user");`

Correct way is, `include("work.php");`

and `$user` is still accessible in `work.php`

Answer (score 1):

include() includes the php code, which is then executed in present context... Its as if that file were part of the one it is included in, you cannot pass parameters

```
include('file.php')
```